# Failed to connect to server - Unable to resolve host "play.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname

Tags: android, http-request

Estou criando um app no Android Studio que irá enviar informações para um web service que fará a inserção dos dados no banco de dados.

Porem quando eu aperto para inserir os dados, o programa retorna esse erro:

```
Failed to connect to server: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "play.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String inserturl = "http://localhost/inserirDados.php";
EditText nome;
EditText endereco;
Button inserir;
Button selecionar;
RequestQueue rq;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
    endereco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEndereco);
    inserir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btEnviarDados);
    selecionar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btMostrarDados);

    rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    inserir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            inserir();
        }
});

}

public void inserir(){
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, inserturl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

        }
    }, new ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parametros.put("nome", nome.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("enredeco", endereco.getText().toString());
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    rq.add(request);

}
}
```

Lembrando que meu AndroidManifest.xml está com as seguintes permissões:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar a entender o que preciso fazer para inserir os dados de um app em um banco de dados externo ?

Comment: localhost aponta para o próprio dispositivo, o ideal seria tu apontar para o domínio ou ip da sua máquina de dev e quando você subir para produção coloca já a URL externa onde se encontra o webservice

Comment: @GeorgeMoura eu ja realizei esse processo e retorna o mesmo erro.

Comment: Já tentou alterar

`rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());`

por

`rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);`

usei como base esse exemplo: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html#simple

Comment: Já realizei esse teste, mas não há mudança e não faz a inserção no banco de dados.

Comment: Vou ver se consigo reproduzir esse erro

Comment: @GeorgeMoura obrigado pela ajuda George, hoje a noite irei ver com um programador Java/Android como fazer para resolver o problema. Caso resolva, posto a solução como resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: como que retorna um erro do host  "play.googleapis.com" se a url esta apontanto para "inserirDados.php"? Pode ser que esse erro venha de outra parte. Outra coisa `localhost` aponta sempre para a propria maquina, no caso do android sempre para o proprio celular entao com essa url nunca vai chegar no servico, vai precisar o ip da maquina, tem tambem o tal do ip magico `10.0.2.2` que na teoria aponta para o localhost da maquina que estiver conectada via usb.